# How to replace javax.microedition.event.Event when porting from Java ME to SE?

Tags: java, events, java-me

When porting a large project with 5000 Java-files from Java ME to Java SE, I have tried to replace [javax.microedition.event.Event](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/meep/api/javax/microedition/event/Event.html) with my own class (same for `EventManager` and `EventListener`):

```
public class Event extends java.util.EventObject {
    protected String mName;
    protected Object mValue;
    protected String mMessage;
    protected Object mInfo;

    public Event(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public Event(String event, String value, String message, Object info) {
        super(null); // throws IllegalArgumentException

        mName = event;
        mValue = value;
        mMessage = message;
        mInfo = info;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the base class `java.util.EventObject` does not like the `source` being `null`.

I have searched around and couldn't find any suitable Java source code.

My question is:

How to write a replacement for the constructor `public Event(String event, String value, String message, Object info)` here? How to set the `source`, where to get it?

Comment: Why/how can your new Events appear without a source object? Won't that break the code that uses the events?

Comment: Why is it a problem? I construct my custom `Event` objects and then `post()` them to my custom `EventManager` (which maintains a `Map` of `Set` of `EventListener` objects - and calls the `handleEvent` method on them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Event extends java.util.EventObject {

    public static final Object UNKNOWN_SOURCE = new Object();

    public Event(String event, String value, String message, Object info) {
        super(UNKNOWN_SOURCE);

        mName = event;
        mValue = value;
        mMessage = message;
        mInfo = info;
    }
```

Comment: I am curious how Java ME handles this, but couldn't find any source code for Java ME. Do they have a similar `UNKNOWN_SOURCE` Object?